# Invoke MSVC C compiler from a python script

Tags: python, c, visual-studio

I am taking a course in C, and I decided to write a little script in python that would compile the homework questions we are given and run them against test files containing input and expected output.

It was straightforward to compile the code with the `gcc` or `clang` compilers from the script. I just needed to run `shutil.which(compiler)` where `compiler` is either `gcc` or `clang` to get the compiler's path, and then invoke it using the `subprocess` module to compile the code.

The problem I am facing is handling the Microsoft MSVC compiler for Windows. Some students who use Windows like to use Visual Studio for writing code and I can't blame them for that. I found it quite challenging to invoke the MSVC compiler from a Python script. As opposed to other compilers like `gcc` or `clang`, which are binaries located on the system's PATH and thus discoverable using `shutil.which`, the MSVC compiler isn't usually found directly on the system's PATH. I know that on Windows if you want to invoke the MSVC compiler, mainly accessible from the `cl.exe` binary, you have to open a special developer command prompt that sets up the environment for `cl.exe` to work correctly. This means that a simple `shutil.which("cl.exe")` wouldn't work, and more effort is required to invoke the `cl.exe` compiler. I read that there are certain batch scripts you can use to set up the MSVC compiler such as `vcvarall.bat`. However, I couldn't find an easy and portable way to invoke them from a script.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170#developer_command_file_locations) specifies the location of these scripts in the Visual Studio installation directory, but there doesn't seem to be a portable way to access these locations. What if Visual Studio isn't installed in `C:\Program Files`, but elsewhere? How can I determine the version and edition of Visual Studio programmatically? What if only the VisualC++ tools are installed and not Visual Studio itself? Where would the scripts be located then?

There doesn't seem to be an environment variable or other portable tool that holds this information, so it looks like any attempt to find these scripts will be system dependent and is doomed to fail on a system with a custom installation.

Even if I manage to get these scripts programmatically, the documentation doesn't give a clear example of how to use them. I have no experience with using the MSVC compilers outside Visual Studio, so I don't know how to use these scripts and invoke the `cl.exe` compiler.

Can anyone find an easy and portable way to invoke the MSVC compilers from a Python script? Visual Studio is an extremely common C/C++ IDE on Windows, so I would like my script to be capable of invoking the MSVC compilers. If you can provide an example of how this could be accomplished, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not devops developer myself, but AFAIK building scripts usually make a lot of assumptions as to where to look for compiler binaries etc. Making an "universal" script that gets compiler path right every time is a challenging task, and IMO an impractical one. Maybe you're better off assumign that MSVC is always in, say, "C:/MSVC", and even if it isn't, it would require user to make shortcut/softlink to the proper MSVC directory before using your script? That much of cooperation from end user shouldn't be a big deal, I guess.

Comment: Find the specific directory on your computer, and (1) explicitly add to your PATH or (2) hardcode it in the python script. The correct way to handle repetitive builds is to use a build system -- CMake is king in C++ land, but setting that up for the first time is likely more trouble than it's worth for your class.